# Problemas para recoger todos los datos de un array

Tags: php, html, formularios

Tengo un problema para recoger todos los datos seleccionados de un select múltiple en un formulario. Cuando el usuario maraca varias opciones y se recibe un correo con los datos solo llega uno de ellos y no todos los seleccionados. No encuentro el problema y os agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda.

```
     <div class="input-group">
            <label for="phone">¿Ha introducido cambios en sus hábitos o en su dieta? Marque cuáles…</label>
            <br>
            <select  name="cambios[]" multiple="multiple">
              <option id="ctrl" value="Dejar de fumar">Dejar de fumar</option>
              <option id="ctrl" value="Protegerme de la luz" selected>Protegerme de la luz</option>
              <option id="ctrl" value="Priorizar cierto tipo de alimentos">Priorizar cierto tipo de alimentos</option>
            </select>
          </div>



    if (isset($_POST['cambios'])){
  $cambio=$_POST['cambios'];
 foreach ($_POST['cambios'] as $cambio){
  $dieta =($cambio) ;
 }
};
```

Comment: Dentro del `foreach` estás sobrescribiendo el contenido de `$dieta` en cada iteración, por lo que al salir de bucle, `$dieta` contendrá el último valor del array `$_POST['cambios']`

Comment: y cual cres que seria la mejor solución ? mil gracias de verdad

Comment: No sé como quieres mostrar esos valores en tu correo. Quizá podrías concatenarlos en una variable para mostrar esos valores separados por coma. Para eso, dentro del `foreach` podrías usar algo como esto: `$dieta .= $cambio . ', '` El `.=` hace que el nuevo valor vaya concatenado al final del **string** en vez de sobrescribir el contenido de la variable.

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad tu ayuda fue muy importante ya que estaba atascado en este punto.